# jquery-ui accordion issue: animation freezes + content not showing when clicking

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I was trying jQueryUI accordion. I created a test site, copied the code and put things in place. It works fine.

Then I tried to put it in my website. In my website, I have two menu. One is horizontal, on the top. The other is vertical, to the left. I intend to apply accordion to the vertical menu. The vertical menu will also change when different item in the top horizontal menu is clicked.

First thing I did was testing it on my homepage, just to see if there is any conflicts with my current design. The code for the vertical menu is like this:

```
<!-- leftFrame begin -->
<div id="leftFrame">
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>homepage11111111</p>
        </div>

        <h3><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>homepage22222222</p>
        </div>

        <h3><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>homepage33333333</p>
            <ul>
                <li>List item</li>
                <li>List item</li>
                <li>List item</li>
                <li>List item</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#othercontent">Link to other content</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- leftFrame end -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here came the problem. The first penal was expanded as default. When I clicked on a different panel, the content under that panel was not shown. It just expanded a little bit and froze there. The first panel did not collapse either. All panels became not click-able. Like the screenshot below:

[image]

Interesting thing was, if I put the accordion part in a seperate leftmenu.html file and use "$('#leftFrame').load(leftmenu.html)" to load it into the "leftFrame" div. Everything works again.

My first thought was some other javascript or css in the homepage might affect this. I tried to comment out part then all of other javascript or css. It was still not working on the homepage while working fine with the .load function.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance
Milo

Comment: That works fine on its own (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Yvc7c/), what else is going on on that page? Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: What version of jquery and jquery ui are you using?

Comment: @muistooshort I am using jquery-1.4.4.min.js. Here is the error from console:    c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || b] is not a function
http://localhost/testsite/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Line 155    If I switch to 1.5+, error is:    d.easing[j || k] is not a function
http://localhost/testsite/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js
Line 16    With latest jquery(1.6.4), an error comes immediately when the page is loaded:    f.easing[e.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function
http://localhost/testsite/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
Line 4

Comment: @jk. Please refer to my last comment. With latest jquery, some of my previous designed animation for the top menu don't work.

Comment: What version of jquery ui are you using? I see the jquery version but not the ui version. Only way to try and duplicate your error and help you solve it is to know what versions of BOTH you are using in combination. Also, note any other javascript or jquery you have on the page that may be interfering.

Comment: @jk. I tried jquery-ui-1.7.3 and jquery-ui.1.8.16. Same issue with both. If it is the version issue, why does it work when using the .load() function?

Comment: Then you have something else interfering. Here is @mu is too short's fiddle with jquery 1.4.4 and jquery ui 1.8.7: http://jsfiddle.net/Yvc7c/2/ As you can see, it still works even in dom ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out to be an easing conflict between different js files. Just make sure to use only one version of easing function.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have your answer, but for others, I had a similar issue with the same weird behavior when I was adding new sections via a clone.

I cloned the first (only) section of the accordion, appended it to the end, then changed the title and contents to suit my need.  After that, I destroyed and re-added the accordion to ensure it worked with the new contents.  After that, multiple (all new) sections showed as the active one (due to the clone) and when I clicked them, they would initially work but suddenly stop working at some point.

To resolve this issue, I did the following:

1. Moved the destroy prior to the clone/append
2. cloned/appended my new sections
3. modified my section content as needed
4. Added back the accordion functionality.

Hope this helps someone along the line.